# write('\n') command does not deposit new line

Tags: python, arrays, file

I am working on a convertor file in colab python. When creating the txt file on specific places I need it to write down the 0 and change line, although it does not.

Please help, here is my code:

```
f=open('dimac_outfs1.txt')
with open('dimac_outfs1.txt','a') as writefile:
  for i in range(len(my_array)):
    if my_array[i]!=0: 
      writefile.write(str(my_array[i]))             
    else:
      writefile.write(str(str(my_array[i] + '\n'))
```

even trying

```
 else:
      writefile.write(str(my_array[i]))
      writefile.write("\n")
```

does not help.

my_array is an numpy.ndarray witch consists of: array(['-1', ' ', '-2', ..., ' ', '0', ' '], dtype='<U21') it has possitive and negative integers as well as zero and spaces.

Comment: We can't see `my_array` so we have no idea whether that branch of the code (that writes the newline) even runs. Likely `if my_array[i]!=0:` is _always_ `True` because you're comparing against an integer and I bet all your numerical data is a string

Comment: my_array is an numpy.ndarray witch consists of: array(['-1', ' ', '-2', ..., ' ', '0', ' '], dtype='<U21') it has possitive and negative integers as well as zeros

Comment: If the contents were integers, it would be `array([-1, -2, -3,  1,  2,  3])`, not `array(['-1', ' ', '-2', ..., ' ', '0', ' '],,...')`

Comment: If `my_array[i] + '\n'` doesn't throw an error then it is a valid string, in which case the `str(str())` is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you command does not work.
I think if you check the debugger you will notice that there is an EOL error in :

```
 else:
      writefile.write(str(str(my_array[i] + '\n'))
```

You are missing a parenthesis.
Otherwise, the

```
with open(<file>,'a') as f:
f.write(str(i)+'\n')
```

works so I guess the EOL error should be the one.

Also tips that lazy me loves :

I can recommand you to put a '\n' at the beginning of your code if you append to file.

Make sure you are in the right path, and if needed, put the absolute path of the file you append to.

Python being very good to simplify everything, you can also use your for loop this way :

```
for elem in list :
```

elem will at each loop be list[0], list[1] etc.

Hoping I answered your question